# How to rename a specific cell in R?

Tags: r, rename

I just want to change the "District of Columbia" to "D.C."

[image: fig]

[image]

Comment: Is that a data frame? If so does the column have a name?

Comment: You need to add some additonnal information about the data.

Answer (score 10):

If you have a data frame, you can refer to a position using row and column number. So to change row 9, column 1 of data frame `data`:

```
data[9, 1] <- "D.C."
```

If you had for example a column named `state`, you could use the column name:

```
data[9, "state"] <- "D.C."
```

If you wanted to change all occurrences in the `state` column:

```
data$state <- gsub("District of Columbia", "D.C.", data$state)
```

Comment: How do I edit a value over multiple rows? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376988/rename-value-for-multiple-rows-based-on-other-variable

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do if you have a matrix:

```
x <- matrix(c(9, "District of Columbia", "DC", 59),nrow=1 ) 
x[x == "District of Columbia"] <- "DC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `%>% mutate( colname = "D.C")`?

I think you could try an If_else aswell if you have different states

`mutate(df, Colname = if_else(DC, "D.C",))` this might empty the other cells but worth trying.